# SQL - How do I get 1 empty column per row in a related table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, pivot

I am trying to write a SQL query that adds a certain amount of empty columns, based on the number of rows in a related table (t1) for a Crystal Report. These columns should have the header of the name of the dataset.

So it should look something like this:

[image: Table]

However I would need to change the script each time a new row gets added (e.g. opening a store - not very often, but it does happen).

I thought about using the pivot function, but I believe the number of rows must be defined - plus, there is no calculation / aggregation happening.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. Most certainly, however, you are going to need dynamic SQL, so is this *really* the path you want to go down?

Comment: Statically, I would write something like this:       

`with a as ([select sql statement here]),  
b as (select top 0  
 null as [MS 2],  
 null as [MS 1],  
 null as [MS 3],
 null as [MS 5], 
 null as [MS 4]
from
 xtrade.KUNDE
)

select * from a cross join b `

The expected result should look something like the table in the post.

However I try to write a dynamic statement, that gets the same result as cte b - thanks for the advice until here

Comment: Crystal Reports can crosstab, and it would be better to get CR to do this than the DB. DB queries are not supposed to have varying numbers of columns (rowcounts vary, column counts do not). This feels very much like a "front end's problem, not back end's"

Comment: If Crystal is able to do this, even better
I am diving into that. Thanks for the input

Comment: Crosstab does not really work for me in that example.
However I could use Dynamic SQL to achieve the result.
I am posting the SQL below.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the result using dynamic SQL.
The Script looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @STRSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'WITH a AS (SELECT ';
DECLARE @Kst nvarchar(6);
DECLARE @Markt NVARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(50) = 'XTRADE';


DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT NUMMER, BEZEICHNUNG 
    from XTRADE.KUNDE 
    where NUMMER > 99 and NUMMER not in (194, 196, 198) 
            and (DATUM_SCHLIESSUNG > GETDATE() or DATUM_SCHLIESSUNG is null)
    order by    BEZEICHNUNG


    OPEN C1

            PRINT @Kst + ' ' + @Markt
            FETCH NEXT
            FROM C1 into @Kst, @Markt       
    
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN
            SET @STRSQL = @STRSQL + 'null as [' + @Markt + '], '
            FETCH NEXT
            FROM C1 into @Kst, @Markt
        END


    CLOSE C1

DEALLOCATE C1;

SET @STRSQL = left(@STRSQL, len(@Strsql) - 1) + ')'

DECLARE @Statement nvarchar(max) = ', b as (select 1 as Col1, 1 as Col2, 5 as Col3 union all select 2,2,12 union all select 3, 3, 42)';
DECLARE @Exec nvarchar(max) = @STRSQL + @Statement + 'select * from b cross join a';

print @Exec;
exec sp_executesql @Exec
```

Answer (score 1):

As Larnu already mentioned, dynamic SQL would be one way to go. I would suggest using a combination of XML PATH and dynamic SQL. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @colList VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',NULL as t1_row' + cast(col1 AS varchar(3))
                                   FROM MyTable
                                   FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Txt
                                )

DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ' + @colList + ' FROM MyTable'

EXEC (@stmt)
```